# How do I get my class variables properties into Winform controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I have multiple classes, one of which is called the 'Variable class' where I 
    `{get;set;}`
 my values obtained from other classes. Accessing these values in voids is simply:

```
Private void (Variables vb) 
{    
}
```

However in the 'Load' part of Winforms,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

From the Variables Class:

```
public class Variables
{
public int Node { get; set; }
}
```

The `object sender, EventArgs e` part is occupying the space where I place the arguments. Is there any way that I could obtain `Node` from the class `Variables`on the winform?

Comment: Put then in the constructor of the form - you can's pass variables to the form's `Load` event.

Comment: you probably need to do a tutorial on winforms / C#.  Sounds like you are very new

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Lodestone6 I am trying to access the values on the winform from the other class. Let's say that I want to display the value in a text box.

Comment: Add the code for your Variables class to the question. You are asking the question incorrectly. You most likely want to ask "How do I get my class variables properties into Winform controls?"

Comment: @Marc Lyon Editted. Thanks.

Comment: Google search _"WinForms data binding tutorial"_.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Your method `Form1_Load` is an *event handler* (because it usually gets called as a result of some event occurring). The "Load" event is defined by WinForms, so you cannot change the fact that the arguments are `object sender` and `EventArgs e`.

WinForms creates one instance of your `Form1` class before it displays your form. Whenever an event happens on your form, the event handler on that same object is called.

So, you can store values in fields and properties of your `Form1` class:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    Variables _myVariables;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myVariables = new Variables() { Node = 10 }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The current value of _myVariables.Node is: " + _myVariables.Node);
    }
}
```

If your `Variables` object is created outside your form, then you can pass it into your `Form1` constructor:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    Variables _myVariables;

    public Form1(Variables variables)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myVariables = variables;
    }

    // ...
}


// Then, somewhere else:

var variables = new Variables() { Node = 10 };
var myForm = new Form1(variables);
myForm.Show();
// or: Application.Run(myForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but I think I can help.

```
    namespace Example
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            //class which can be used anywhere in the namespace
            public class exampleClass
            {
                public const string SETSTATE = "0";
                public const string GETSTATE = "1";
                public const string SETVALUE = "2";
                public const string GETVALUE = "3";
                public const string SENDFILE = "4";
                public const string STATE_RP = "129";
                public const string VALUE_RP = "131";
                public const string STATUS_RP = "128";
            }
        }
   }
```

you can use exampleClass, and any of its enclosed members, anywhere within Form1 here.  You do not need to pass it anywhere within the form to use it.  You could add a function later that uses it directly like:

```
void exampleF()
        {
           //note that when you are accessing properties of UI elements from
           //a non-UI thread, you must use a background worker or delegate
           //to ensure you are doing so in a threadsafe way. thats a different problem though.
           this.txtYourTextBox.txt = exampleClass.GETSTATE;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your attempt is it actually to use MVP-Pattern in WinForms. Very good idea. 
Then you can use DataBinding to Bind your Forms-Controls to your "Variables classes" properties. Your variable class takes the presenter role, your form is the view, and your model(s) are the sources of your variable classes data.

Unfortunately, the pattern uses some advanced mechanisms you have to deal with.

For more information, you might take a first look here: 
[Databinding in MVP winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653993/databinding-in-mvp-winforms)